# How to end with one result with an if statement on java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, statements

```
if (number1 + 8 == number2 || number1 - 8 == number2){

         if (name1.equals(name2)){

             if (cod1 == cod2){

                if (some1.equals(some2)){

                System.out.println("They're in the same group");
                }

             System.out.println("They are in the same column");;
             }

       System.out.println("They are in the same section");
       }

  System.out.println("They are in the same subgroup");
  }

    else{
    System.out.println("They are different");
     }
  }
}
```

How could I change this so that I only get one message at the end? Right now it gives all the messages or just the They are different. I know I can't put an actual break since this isn't a loop, but what action could I take in this problem? Would I have to rewrite it? Thank You for the help.

Comment: use `else` wherever appropriate..

Answer (score 1):

`String output = "";`, and then replace all your `System.out.println`s to `output =` and change the string to whatever the appropriate output would be.  Also, the string assignment needs to come before the nested if.

Then outside the outermost `if else`, do `System.out.println(output);`

```
String output = "";
if (number1 + 8 == number2 || number1 - 8 == number2){
    output = "They are in the same subgroup";
    if (name1.equals(name2)){
        output="They are in the same section";
        if (cod1 == cod2){
            output="They are in the same column";
            if (some1.equals(some2)){
                output="They're in the same group";
            }
        }
    }
}

else{
    output="They are different";
}

System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (number1 + 8 == number2 || number1 - 8 == number2) {

    if ("abc".equals("def")) {

        if (cod1 == cod2) {

            if (some1.equals(some2)) {

                System.out.println("They're in the same group");
            } else

                System.out.println("They are in the same column");
            ;
        } else

            System.out.println("They are in the same section");
    } else

        System.out.println("They are in the same subgroup");
}

else {
    System.out.println("They are different");
}
```

Use else conditions with if.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the relationship between groups, columns and sections but you may be able to do something like this where you check the most specific case first. This avoids the many levels of nested conditions.

```
if (some1.equals(some2)) {
  System.out.println("They're in the same group");
} else if (cod1 == cod2) {
  System.out.println("They are in the same column");
} else if (name1.equals(name2)) {
  System.out.println("They are in the same section");
} else if (number1 + 8 == number2 || number1 - 8 == number2) {
  System.out.println("They are in the same subgroup");
} else {
  System.out.println("They are different");
}
```

**It will work only if groups are unique across all columns** -- for example, checking whether two organisms are the same species, then broadening to check genus, and then family would be valid because you won't have the same species name in different genuses; but using this to test if house addresses are equal by first checking the street name is not valid because you will have streets with the same name in different cities.

Comment: This is not the same logic. Compare your code with OP's code when names are the same but cod is different.

Comment: If groups are unique across all columns, this is valid; if groups are repeated in different columns, it is not. We don't really know enough about the data to say what the case is. I mentioned that in the paragraph immediately following the code.